# How to parse this json in azure data factory in copy operation

Tags: json, azure, blob, azure-data-factory, jsonpath

{"Properties"::\"{\"receivedPushNotificationMessage\""Received push notification: {\n    aps =     {\n        alert = \\"Network programmer push\\";\n    };\n    channelToken = \\"eyJ0eXAiO\",\"time\":\"2019-02-26_11-32-03-AM\"}"},{"AppBuild":"321"},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON format is supported in file type dataset.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#json-format